# What kind of feedback is this?

Tags: airliner, aircraft-maintenance

i found this link that shows a united airlines intercom feeding back and i was just wondering how typical is this on these flights?? i’ve never heard feedback come back frequently every time the speakers are on

is it from the mic?

i need an answer

Comment: I don't think you will get any verifiably correct answers because this isn't a reportable incident that the FAA tracks.  FWIW, I have never noticed feedback being a problem.  And why do you "need" an answer, vs just want to know?  P.S.  This is probably a better fit on Travel SE.

Answer (score 2):

This is standard [audio feedback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback) caused in the standard way: The active microphone was too close to a speaker, generating a feedback loop.

We can't say for certain why this happened here but not on most flights. Perhaps the flight attendant was closer to a speaker than usual.